# How do I version control updated already imported files?

Tags: svn

Need to version controll imported codes. 
I imported **myProject/** to svn repo **https://svn.host/myProject/**. 
So **myProject/** on my local computer is not version controlled. 
After the import, I started doing changes to code on my local computer and now would like to version control it. My local copy of the code is newest. Want to version control so that I can do 
 `svn commit` and easily merge the codes. 
Working in terminal.

Comment: Perform a check-out at another location on your local PC, then copy your modified files to this new location (copy everything, overwriting some files), then commit from this location after a last check.

Comment: @LaurentH. src code paths on my local computer hardcoded in many places, sensitive for movements. Cannot move files to new location.

Comment: No problem with that. After the commit, you can delete your source code folder on your local computer. Then perform a checkout to retrieve it. And you're done !